# Issue with pattern matching of urls in seneca when hierarchy is the same

Tags: javascript, express, seneca

I have 2 urls like :

1. /test/run
2. /test/{test_id}

I have 2 separate routes for them like:

```
1. {
prefix: '/test',
pin: 'role:test,cmd:*',
map:{
run: {GET: true}
}
}

2. {
pin: 'role:test,cmd:*',
map:{
test: {GET: true, suffix: '/:test_id'} 
} 
}
```

However when I access /test/run. The second pattern gets triggered with run as a URL parameter.

Is this the expected behaviour or is there some other way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set different patterns (
*Otherwise seneca will not be able to distinguish them*)

*pin*

for the seneca plugins with `seneca.use('role:web', {..})` and action   `seneca.act('role:test,cmd:test,action:byId', (..)=>{..})`

```
{
 prefix: '/test',
 pin: 'role:test,cmd:*',
 map:{
 run: {GET: true}
}

{
 prefix: '/test',
 pin: 'role:test,cmd:*,action:byId',
 map:{
 test: {GET: true, suffix: '/:test_id'} 
}
```

Comment: Hi @Shobhit Srivastava, has my answer fulfilled your question? :)